# Tests fail when using @InjectRepository: Nest can't resolve Repository

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I'm using NestJs with Typeorm, normal setup. UsersService gets the Typeorm Repository injected:

```
constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private usersRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}
```

In the UsersModule:

```
@Module({
  imports:[ TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
  controllers: [UsersController ],
  providers: [UsersService]
})
```

Nothing special as you can see. But the auto-generated test for UsersService fails, no matter what I do:

```
describe('UsersService', () => {
  let service: UsersService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [UsersService],      
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<UsersService>(UsersService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

I get the following error:

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (?). Please
> make sure that the argument UserRepository at index [0] is available
> in the RootTestModule context.

The solutions on Stackoverflow that I found seem to be obsolete, or over-complicated. I understand that the problem stems from the usage of @InjectRepository.

What is the solution? I tried downloading other people's fairly-similar projects, and get the same error! Both with nest 8 and 7.

Answer (score 9):

Nest can't resolve the dependency because you don't provide the repository in the testing module. If you're doing unit tests you probably want to mock the repository using a custom provider:

```
 import { getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

 describe('UsersService', () => {
   let service: UsersService;
   let repository: Repository<User>;

   beforeEach(async () => {
     const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
       providers: [
         UsersService,
         {
           provide: getRepositoryToken(User),
           useValue: {},
         }
       ],      
     }).compile();

     service = module.get<UsersService>(UsersService);
   });

   it('should be defined', () => {
     expect(service).toBeDefined();
   });
})
```

You can provide an object, a class or a factory function, more details in the doc: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers

Then in your tests you can mock the methods of the repository this way:

```
jest.spyOn(repository, 'find').mockResolvedValueOnce([])
```

It's not the only way to mock, but that's a simple and standard one.

Comment: And what if i don't want to mock? how do i just inject the "normal" repository?

Answer (score 3):

The docs are pretty clear on how to write tests when using `@nestjs/typeorm`: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#testing

There are a bunch of samples here as well: https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to "solve" this myself. I should've mentioned perhaps that i didn't intend to do any mocking, but wanted the test to work "as is"(I prefer using a test-dedicated DB, rather than mocking units. Seems more realistic to me).

So it appears i kind of misunderstood, that every call to createTestingModule() needs to make sure all relevant dependencies are created, **including** stuff like ORM initialization, which is usually done in the AppModule(here i'm testing a service in UserModule..). So what I did in users.service.specs.ts:

```
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]), TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
        type: 'postgres',
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 5432,
        username: 'postgres',
        password: '',
        database: 'postgres',
        schema: 'test-db',
        entities: [User],
        synchronize: true,
      }), TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
      providers: [UsersService],
    }).compile();
```

Notice that I had to both create the TypeOrm connection, and register the entity.
Now I understand that each test suite is totally isolated, and therefore needs all relevant dependencies to be passed to it, **even if in the "original" application this code is already imported in the root module**.